Getting Compilation Failure "cannot find symbol for concatMap" in the RxJava Code
I am new to this RxJava coding language.
I am trying to write a function that recursively copies files from one S3 location and pastes the content to another S3 location.
Here is the code that I have written for this
private Single<CopyObjectResponse> copyObjectsRecursively(String sourceBucketName, String sourceKeyPrefix,String destinationBucketName, String destinationKeyPrefix) {
        return listObjects(sourceKeyPrefix, sourceBucketName)
                .concatMap(listObjectsV2Response -> Observable.fromIterable(listObjectsV2Response.contents())
                        .flatMapSingle(s3Object -> {
                            if (s3Object.key().endsWith("/")) {
                                String newSourceKey = s3Object.key();
                                String newDestinationKey = buildDestinationKey(destinationKeyPrefix, newSourceKey, sourceKeyPrefix);
                                return copyObjectsRecursively(sourceBucketName, newSourceKey, destinationBucketName, newDestinationKey);
                            } else {
                                CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
                                        .sourceBucket(sourceBucketName)
                                        .sourceKey(s3Object.key())
                                        .destinationBucket(destinationBucketName)
                                        .destinationKey(buildDestinationKey(destinationKeyPrefix, s3Object.key(), sourceKeyPrefix))
                                        .build();
                                return Single.fromFuture(buildClient.copyObject(copyRequest));
                            }
                        }))
                .ignoreElements()
                .toSingleDefault(null)
                .onErrorResumeNext(error -> Single.error(error));
    }

The problem with this code is, this is complaining that
cannot find symbol 
[ERROR]   symbol:   method concatMap((listObjec[...] } })) 
[ERROR]   location: class io.reactivex.Single<software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Response>

I have check that I have correct imports in my code
import io.reactivex.Single; 
import io.reactivex.Completable; 
import io.reactivex.Observable;

But this is still complaining
I tried looking at all the imports in my code, Checked the version of RxJava(2.x.x) but still this is not able to find the concatMap symbol in the code.

According to the RxJava Javadoc, this method was introduced in version 3.0.0:

Since:
3.0.0

Since you state to be using version 2.x.x, this is not available in your version. Upgrade RxJava or provide a different implementation, e.g. using flatMap().

Tried updating the version
[INFO]    io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:jar:3.1.5:compile
But it is still complaining with the same error.
